# Program using boost::filesystem links with clang but not gcc

Tags: c++, linker, boost-filesystem

I have an extremely simple program using `boost::filesystem`, taken from the library's tutorial.

```
// fs_example.cpp
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main() {
  path p = current_path();
  directory_iterator it{p};
  while (it != directory_iterator()) {
    std::cout << *it++ << '\n';
  }
}
```

I'm building it with the following extremely simple script, which should be providing the right arguments in the right order to the linker:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -u

${CXX} \
    -Wall \
    -Werror \
    --std=c++14 \
    -lboost_system \
    -lboost_filesystem \
    -o fs_example \
    fs_example.cpp
```

using `env CXX=clang++ ./build.sh`, the program compiles and links

```
$ env CXX=clang++ ./build.sh
$ ls
build.sh*  fs_example*  fs_example.cpp
```

using `env CXX=g++ ./build.sh`, the program fails to compile.

```
$ env CXX=g++ ./build.sh 
/tmp/ccFcZ3W6.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
fs_example.cpp:(.text+0x1c1): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is GCC producing a link-time error when Clang isn't? How do I go about diagnosing why the linker isn't able to find symbols in `boost::system` in the GCC path even though the argument is provided?

Comment: Note that it's `-std=c++14` not `--std=c++14`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assume "one-pass linking" which means the lower-level `boost_system` must appear after the higher-level `boost_filesystem`.